# Play framework not working - missing packages

Tags: playframework

Well, I've been at this for hours now with no success.

I tried installing the Play framework in my PC but when I compile/run any new or sample project (either in the command line or in Lightbend Activator) the errors are always the same:

```
Filters.java:1: error: package javax.inject does not exist;
...
Filters.java:2: error: package play does not exist;
...
Filters.java:3: error: package play.mvc does not exist;
```

I tried everything that I found online and still haven't solved the problem. What I tried:

-Reinstalled JDK 1.8.0_102 in a folder without empty spaces (such as Program Files) and added the new directory to PATH;

-Installed SBT (even though Activator supposedly already has it) and added to PATH;

-Installed and tested with multiple versions of playframework. 2.5,2.4 and 2.2.

Other info:
-The java.exe and javac.exe are included in PATH;

My OP is Windows 10 64-bit.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens if you run `activator update`? Can you provide the link of the sample you are trying?

Comment: It completed an update but the error still exists. Here is the link of the sample [project](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/templates/play-java-intro).

Comment: Well,actually the problem is solved and I quite don't understand why. After the `activator update`, all I did was a JAVA_HOME variable which should have done nothing since the directory for Java was already in PATH.

Comment: Hi @JoãoPereira...Can you  please elaborate ..how did you solve this problem..???...